# How do I prevent Linux kernel from responding to incoming TCP packets?

Tags: linux, tcpip, sockets

For my application, I need to intercept certain TCP/IP packets and route them to a different device over a custom communications link (not Ethernet).  I need all the TCP control packets and the full headers.  I have figured out how to obtain these using a raw socket using socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP).  This works well and allows me to attach filters to just see the TCP port I'm interested in.

However, Linux also sees these packets.  By default, it sends a RST when it receives a packet to a port number it doesn't know about.  That's no good as I plan to send back a response myself later.  If I open up a second "normal" socket on that same port using socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) and listen() on it, Linux then sends ACK to incoming TCP packets.  Neither of these options is what I want.  I want it to do *nothing* with these packets so I can handle everything myself.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/) to block the packets from normal processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### iptables

You can drop those packets at the OUTPUT chain of the FILTER table.

#### The protocol

RFC 793 (TCP) specifies the RST-sending behavior

```
SEGMENT ARRIVES

  If the state is CLOSED (i.e., TCB does not exist) then [...]:
  An incoming segment not containing a RST causes a RST to be sent in response.
```

And linux obiviously implements it correctly.

#### The sysctl interface

It seems the behaviour is also not tweakable through the  sysctl interface (see [tcp(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp)).  In any event, that man page is definitely a good read if you haven't already come across it yet.

#### Kernel code

Depending on what you actually want to acheive, altering the kernel code directly might be an option.

Comment: I will look into `iptables`.  Could they also be used to stop those packets on the way _in_?  It seems it would be better to keep the kernel from seeing that TCP traffic in the first place.

Comment: Yes of course.  In this case it's the INPUT chain of the FILTER table

Comment: My limited version of uClinux wasn't including iptables support, but I was able to add it.  It is working great - just one call does the trick.  Thanks.